# Errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed" al crear llave foránea

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Estoy intentando crear una llave foránea, sin embargo estoy recibiendo un error. Aún no entiendo muy bien lo que sucede y soy muy nuevo en esto de MySQL. A continuación dejo el código que usé para crear la llave foránea y el error que me salta:

```
CREATE TABLE pais (
id VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE persona (
id INT NOT NULL,
nombres VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
apellidos VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
edad INT,
website VARCHAR(128),
estado ENUM('activo', 'inactivo') DEFAULT 'inactivo',
pais INT NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(estado)
);
MariaDB [Valentin]> ALTER TABLE usuario
    ->         ADD CONSTRAINT foranea
    ->         FOREIGN KEY (pais)
    ->         REFERENCES pais(id)
    ->         ON UPDATE CASCADE
    ->         ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

> ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table `valentin`.`usuario` (errno: 150 "Foreign key constraint is incorrectly formed")

Comment: ahi te dice que no esta correctamente formada, porque la haces con un alter?

Comment: No veo declarada tu tabla usuario como para que quieras modificarla.

Answer (score 0):

Como mencionan en los comentarios de la pregunta, la tabla `usuario` no está definida en su pregunta, sin embargo, asumiré que se refiere a la tabla `persona`.

El problema se produce porque los tipos de datos de la columna `pais` son distintos en las dos tablas (`pais` y `persona`). En la tabla `pais` el tipo de dato es: `VARCHAR(2)` y en la tabla `persona` el tipo de dato es: `INT`.

Asumiré el tipo de dato `VARCHAR(2)` como el correcto (debe verificarlo y ajustarlo según necesite):

```sql
CREATE TABLE pais (
  id VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  nombre VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE persona (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  nombres VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  apellidos VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  email VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
  edad INT,
  website VARCHAR(128),
  estado ENUM('activo', 'inactivo') DEFAULT 'inactivo',
  -- pais INT NOT NULL,
  pais VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(estado)
);

-- ALTER TABLE usuario
ALTER TABLE persona
  ADD CONSTRAINT foranea
  FOREIGN KEY (pais) REFERENCES pais (id)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

Ver [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=79d84a82f5339245a934d410da9988b3).